# Java: Should I use constructor to do more than just initializing the variables

Tags: java, android, methods, constructor

I am working with Android and java projects. My task is to create a class which should draw a rectangle on the canvas. I wanted to know, if it is a good practice to program a constructor such that it can do more than just initializing the variables. Ofcourse, I am aware that I can create an object of a class, the constructor of which will initialize the variables and then call the public method to draw the rectangle. However, I would like to know if it is a good practice to program the constructor which will also draw the rectangle thus getting rid of the public method.

Any comments would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you want users to be able to call the draw method when they want to? Yes? Then keep it in a public method. No? Then make it private. Either way it should be in a separate method, not in the constructor. You can call it from the constructor, although it's cleaner not to. It might not be expected to immediatly receive a drawn output when you create an object.

Comment: Just a note. The method to draw does **not** to be `public`. You can have it as `private` if you keep it in the same class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What if you wan't to draw several times?
You would create one object per draw, which is more expensive than one method call per draw.
Also, it's not standard, and if anyone else should use this, he would be totally confused (I wouldn't expect it...).

**Don't** do this!

Note that it's perfectly fine to do more than initialization of the variables, for example register some kind of callback registration etc.

But in general, most developers don't expect things like drawing, IO or similar in a constructor.

Answer (score 3):

It's a good practice to do only basic initialization in the constructor. You should avoid all long running operations there. Call them only if you need them.